# Can we assign custom name for network interface on Windows 10?

Tags: network-programming, windows-10, naming-conventions, network-interface

Currently when I connect a second USB ethernet device on windows PC, it shows up as Ethernet 2(or any other name which OS allocates depending on port). Can we customize this name for a specific device that is connected? For example if I connect a second USB wifi adapter from Netgear, I need it to be "Netgear" instead of "wi-fi 2" ?

Comment: I assume you mean programmatically, since you posted here instead of e.g. http://superuser.com/? Then you need to be more specific, like telling us in what programming language you're working, what you have tried so far, how it did or didn't work etc. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and of course [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) (if you haven't done it yet).

Comment: I know that we can rename the interface manually and through the system registry. But I need something which is persistent. I want to know what aspect of windows is responsible for assigning names to network interfaces automatically. I looked through the network driver and host controller driver codes but I could not find where exactly the name allocation is done.